# How do I use CC_CALLBACK for external classes in Cocos2dx v3.2?

Tags: cocos2d-x, menu

I've been having problems with using 'CC_CALLBACK_#' (i.e. CC_CALLBACK_0, CC_CALLBACK_1). It works alright if I am using it to call a function from the class (Using 'GameScene' class for this example) itself like

```
CC_CALLBACK_0(GameScene::gamePause,this)
```

However I am unable to use it to call functions from other classes (i.e. 'SettingsScene') that have been included like

```
CC_CALLBACK_1(SettingsScene::bgmControl,this)
```

I can use the SettingScene CC_CALLBACK code just fine in the SettingsScene class.

In cocos2dx v2, 'menu_selector' did not have any issues calling functions from other classes so I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to do it in v3.2? I really don't want to resort to copying the functions from other classes into the class I want to call it from :(

Thank you so much!

Comment: I am quoting vovkasm's answer from my question at the cocos2dx forum [link](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-do-i-use-cc-callback-for-external-classes-in-cocos2dx-v3-2/19808) for the people here :)
"To call object method, you need:

Method (the first argument to macros)
Object itself (the second argument)
So you snipped of code should look something like:

    CC_CALLBACK_1(SettingsScene::bgmControl, setttingsSceneObject)
And you always can use C++11 feature called 'lambda expression':

    [&](ArgType arg) { settingsSceneObject->bgmControl(arg); }"